# Android : Align image on top right hand corner of button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image which looks like a checkbox, that i would like to align on top right hand corner of button. Have tried relative layout but could not achieve desired result.  Any suggestion to achieve the desired result?

[image: Checkbox]

[image: What i want]

I have tried using Framelayout but the checbox image remains hidden

```
 <FrameLayout 
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/filter_check"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/checkmark"
             android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            style="@style/Widget.Button.White.BlueText.BlueStroke"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter" />


    </FrameLayout>
```

After Farouk's suggestions to use Button before image. Here is the code

```
<FrameLayout 
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        style="@style/Widget.Button.White.BlueText.BlueStroke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Filter" />

      <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/filter_check"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/checkmark"
         android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is what i see on designer.

[image: FrameLayout Output]

Not sure how to move the checkbox image up and right.

**In case you want the solution, here it is:**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            style="@style/Widget.Button.White.BlueText.BlueText.FrameImage"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sort" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:src="@drawable/checkmark" />
    </FrameLayout>


  <style name="Widget.Button.White.BlueText.BlueText.FrameImage" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_button_blue_stroke_bg_selector</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
```

Solution:

[image]

Comment: What about using FrameLayout ?

Comment: The button should come before the ImageView. It will works for yoy then.

Comment: @FaroukTouzi That helps, but i am not able to get the alignment of checkbox image right.

Comment: Edit your response and show your code again please.

Comment: @FaroukTouzi I have changed it, please take a look.

Comment: Look to my answser below please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It look like this :

[image]

Just play with the `android:paddingTop="-10dp"` as you like.

Here the code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:text="Sort"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_title_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingTop="-10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbtn" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it, but layout_margin="7dp" on the button is not giving me the desired shape of button. When i remove the margin on button and try adjusting the paddingTop of Imageview it gets clipped. Which i think is expected behaviur.  Will try playing around with padding and margin.

Comment: I was able to make it work by adjusting margin and padding. Thanks!

Comment: When I see in the designer, I can see the close as desired. But when I run the application, it is invisible. How?

Comment: It's not padding it should be margin.

Answer (score 7):

Check this one, hopefully it will help you.  [image: Here is the image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_widget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="center" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT** If you want to move checkbox little further to imageview then increase the `android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"` to `android:layout_marginLeft="-20dip"`. Just play with it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but its an image which look like a checkbox. Not a checkbox. Would like to align image on top right hand corner of a regular button in Android.

Comment: Replace the checkbox with ImageView. This is the general layout. Accept my answer if it helped you so that it will be easy for others who face same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to add the dot over a drawable (create a new drawable with layer-list with dot at right top corner)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/any_drawable">
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active_dot"  android:gravity="right|top"/>
</layer-list>
```

active_dot.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">

    <size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>

    <solid android:color="#B01212"/>
</shape>
```