# How to create selected image in Gridview with overlay

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, overlay

I want to implement image view like attached image. When I select image on this gridview then new overlay will added with 'true' mark.

[image]

How can i implement this ?

**Note** : Here my gridview does not have static content means image will be from service.

Thanks.!!

Comment: what you have tried ? have you tried it using FrameLayout ? and see following post for help :[Android : Align image on top right hand corner of button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119039/android-align-image-on-top-right-hand-corner-of-button)

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K : I think i can do this by overlapping translucent image..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ImageView object in the layout, which will be filled later with the image from the service.

On top of that, you create a new ImageView with the same dimensions, and add the checkmark as source. If it's not working you can always put them both in a Relative Layout and center the check mark inside it. Set the visibility to GONE.

Add an `onClickListener` to the ImageView with your picture, and when it is clicked set the visibility of the check mark to VISIBLE.

Comment: I was thinking about it..!!