# How to add image to tab layout programactically?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I have a tab layout in my apps,I want to add a image to one of the tab when some condition happen.But I have no idea how to do it

**Here is the tab layout look like before any changes**

[image: tab layout before any changes]

**Here is the condition I want to acheive** I want the red image and a text view on the red circle.

[image: tab layout after changes]

**Currently my code for tab layout is look like this**

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

    private void setupTabIcons() {
     tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
     tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
     tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
     tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
     ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
     adapter.addFragment(new 1stFragment(), "One");
     adapter.addFragment(new 2ndFragment(), "Two");
     adapter.addFragment(new 3rdFragment(), "Three");
     adapter.addFragment(new 4thFragment(), "Four");
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So lastly,how can I get control to the tab layout,so I can add the drawable/image to one of the tab?Somebody please point me to the right direction.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use custom layout.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setCustomView(v);
```

**Design your_view.xml layout according your needs**

Comment: sir,the `view v` from where ya??

Comment: to create View of your custom layout which contains your imageview, textview to show in your tab.

Comment: ah..seems like make sense..I will try this asap

Comment: my `your_view.xml` is only the red icon and the text inside right??

Comment: sir,can u tell me how to control this `your_view.xml` inflate exactly the position in pic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119039/android-align-image-on-top-right-hand-corner-of-button

Comment: hi sir,is works,but I wanna ask,how to remove this inflated view,and set back the original icon?can teach me the final step?thanks in advance.

Comment: just do tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(tabIcons[icon_pos]); when you need

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help, It's custom tab layout with badge view supported
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5418